# What causes Visual Studio to generate NLP files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am compiling C# command line applications with Visual Studio 2017. Sometimes I notice that after I compile, my bin folder contains ".nlp" files. If I delete these files my application works. If I create a brand new project from scratch the ".nlp" do not get generated after a compile. So, something changed in my other projects that is causing the ".nlp" files to get get generated. But what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I was compiling with .NET Framework 3.5. When I compile with .NET Framework 4.6.1 the ".nlp" files do not get generated.